# using subselect in mysqli

Tags: mysql

I have a query which works currently, but we added more the possibility of one customer doing more than one test drive. this additional test Drive is on a different table. The customer ID is an auto increment number on the testdriveform table. So I need to check for addition entries, based on the customer id from table 1 in table 2 and list them along withe the rest.

```
SELECT * FROM testdriveform Where SalesAgent not like '%Test%' and SalesAgent like '%$Sales%' and Date between '$sDate' and '$eDate' and Stock != '' order by Date, SalesAgent;
```

I need to add a subselect I think. Something that adds

```
SELECT * FROM testdrives WHERE custID = testdriveform.id
```

phpmyadmin is down on bluehost..again. Anyone?

Comment: I think you just need to `JOIN` these two tables

Answer (score 1):

NO, you don't need a subselect; rather need a `JOIN` between the tables like

```
SELECT td.*, tdf.*
FROM testdriveform tdf 
JOIN testdrives td ON td.custID = tdf.id 
Where tdf.SalesAgent not like '%Test%' 
and tdf.SalesAgent like '%$Sales%' 
and tdf.`Date` between '$sDate' and '$eDate' 
and tdf.Stock != '' 
order by tdf.`Date`, tdf.SalesAgent;
```

Comment: you use tdf and td abit in there, is that something that creates an as type of shorthand, or am I replacing the stuff with actual table names? Also, thank you. I am giving it a go

Comment: OK. so this is only returning the rows from the 2nd table. But its close I feel. Thank you for the lesson in shorthand as well.

Comment: @Griehle, shouldn't be as the suggested query doing a `*` from both tables